# How to track click events with google analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying to record events when users click specific elements, but no events are being recorded. Here's my code:

```
/* JQUERY PREPENDED ALREADY... */

/* STANDARD GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE */
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'mysite.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');

var _gaq = _gaq || [];

/* MY EVENT TRACKING CODE (NOT WORKING) */
$(".logo-btn-js").click( function() {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Clicks', 'Logo', 'User clicked the "logo" on first screen']);
    }
);
$(".websites-btn-js").click( function() {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Clicks', 'Websites', 'User clicked the "websites" btn']);
    }
);
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use google tag manager

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're using [Universal Analytics (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/):

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-12345678-1', 'mysite.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

With [Classic Analytics (ga.js) event syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) (which won't work):

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Clicks', 'Logo', 'User clicked the "logo" on first screen']);
```

To fix, use [Universal Analytics event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) syntax:

```
$(".logo-btn-js").click( function() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Clicks', 'Logo', 'First Screen');
});
```

Comment: From google analytics specs: "Tracking outbound links and forms can be tricky because most browsers will stop executing JavaScript on the current page once a new page starts to load. One solution to this problem is to set the transport field to beacon"    But caniuse.com says beacon api not supported in IE and Safari.  So you would need to wait for ga send to complete before loading the target page.